# Why is useRef not working to reference a canvas element?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

The first console.log (inside the useEffect hook) never executes.

The second console.log prints out `{ current: undefined }`

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export default function Home() {
  const ref = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref)
  }, [ref])

  console.log(ref)

  return <canvas ref={ref} />
}
```

Why does the first console log not execute?

I have also tried to add the ref inside a callback:

```
import React, {useCallback, useRef} from 'react'

function useHookWithRefCallback() {
  const ref = useRef(null)
  const setRef = useCallback(node => {
    if (ref.current) {
      // Make sure to cleanup any events/references added to the last instance
    }
    
    if (node) {
      // Check if a node is actually passed. Otherwise node would be null.
      // You can now do what you need to, addEventListeners, measure, etc.
    }
    
    // Save a reference to the node
    ref.current = node
  }, [])
  
  return [setRef]
}

function Component() {
  // In your component you'll still recieve a `ref`, but it 
  // will be a callback function instead of a Ref Object
  const [ref] = useHookWithRefCallback()
  
  return <div ref={ref}>Ref element</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It executes for me. So maybe the issue is somewhere else? (see snippet for example)

```js
const { useEffect, useRef } = React

function Home() {
  const ref = useRef()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("[ref] : ", ref)
  }, [ref])
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("[ref.current] : ", ref)
  }, [ref.current])

  console.log(ref)

  return <canvas ref={ref} />
}
// Render it
ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Home />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.1.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.1.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

But as a side-note the

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref)
  }, [ref])
```

effect will only execute if you would change the ref value which is not possible since it's initialized as a const ( `const ref = useRef()` ). So what I think you might want is listen for `ref.current` (as used in the second useEffect from the above code snippet)

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend to use another hook if you want to get a reference to a DOM element.

Try [useLayoutEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect) instead of `useEffect`. This hook will execute after the DOM finish adding its elements, I'll also suggest a check that the ref is valid before you attempt to do anything with it like this (baes on your first example):

```
import React, {useCallback, useRef, useLayoutEffect} from 'react'

export default function Home() {
  const ref = useRef(null)
  
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // Check that the ref is properly set
    if (ref.current) {
      // Do whatever you need with it
      console.log(ref.current);
    }
  }, []);

  console.log(ref)

  return <canvas ref={ref} />
}
```